# Google Calendar API with Angular Submit

Tags: angular, google-calendar-api

I am new to using Angular and I want to integrate it with Google Calendar API but I haven't found anything helpful online. I have a submission form that when the user presses submit a calendar event is created on the business's calendar and an invite is sent to the user that hit submit (they input their email as one of the fields). I don't want to have them log in to the website as there is really no need.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

I followed this tutorial but where do I go from there and how do I connect it with my Angular code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the user to explicitly give consent, you will have to implement this feature on the server-side using [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount).

From the documentation:

> Google APIs such as the Prediction API and Google Cloud Storage can act on behalf of your application without accessing user information. In these situations your application needs to prove its own identity to the API, but no user consent is necessary. Similarly, in enterprise scenarios, your application can request delegated access to some resources.
>
> For these types of server-to-server interactions you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end-user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required. (In non-service-account scenarios, your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.)

You can read more about service accounts and how to use them in your application in the following link:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)